# How to use MediaRecorder to save video file to com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, android-external-storage

I set a `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/` path as output file to MediaRecorder

this is the path in SD card

```
DocumentFile videoDocFile = getOutputMediaDocFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, mContext);

//videoDocFile.toString() is content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/4AEA-D5ED%3ADownload/document/4AEA-D5ED%3ADownload%2FMP4_20170922_134638.mp4
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoDocFile.toString());


private static DocumentFile getOutputMediaDocFile(int type, Activity mContext){

    //customPath value is content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/4AEA-D5ED%3ADownload
    String customPath=PreferenceCenter.getCustomPath(mContext);
    Uri myuri = Uri.parse(customPath);
    DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(mContext, myuri);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    DocumentFile mediaFile;
    mediaFile = pickedDir.createFile("video/mp4", "MP4_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    return mediaFile;

}
```

When I call prepare

```
mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```

I get this exception

```
android.support.v4.provider.TreeDocumentFile@3ed6c56: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

If I go to sd card, I can see the mp4 file, but the file is 0 byte

So the path is correct, but I cannot write content to the file

How can I use MediaRecorder to save video file to `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/`?

Comment: which Device you test?

Comment: Device is samsung s7

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new `DocumentFile` named `file` and use `ContentResolver openFileDescriptor(uri, "rwt")` and get a `ParcelableFileDescriptor`, named it: `pfd` and invoke `pfd.getFileDescriptor()` to get a java FileDescriptor named: `fd`. Then, `setOputputFile(fd)`.